# How to set a interval between two photos in UICollecetionView on iOS with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to achieve an effect that the photos occupy all the screen, and when scrolling the photos in the album, there will be an interval between the two photos, and the photos will automatically bounce back to the center after sliding.

I set `minimumLineSpacing` and `isPagingEnabled`, but when I swipe, the image doesn't fill the entire screen, instead, the left side shows the spacing.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Code:

```
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
view.addSubview(mCollectionView)
mCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
mCollectionView.backgroundColor = .white
mCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "PhotoDetailCVCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cvCellIdentifier)
mCollectionView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.edges.equalTo(view)
}
```

Target effect:

When it's at rest：

[image: At rest]

When we move it:

[image: When sliding]

And the current style while still is:

[image: current style]

Comment: You're going to need either a custom layout, or disable paging and handle centering the cells via code. You are setting your `.itemSize` to the **width*** of the screen (also the width of the collection view), and then you're **adding** `10-pts` spacing between the cells. So, your "item + spacing" is actually 10-pts wider than the screen. If you can accept 5-pts of left/right spacing when the cell is centered, you can easily do this by giving the image view in the cell 5-pts leading/trailing constraints.

Comment: @DonMag The `isPagingEnabled` effect is neccessary for this, the system animation is needed. So could you tell me how to make a custom layout to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach - it may or may not fit your needs...

For your cell layout, give the image view 5-pts "padding" on each side:

[image]

When the cells are adjacent (with flow layout set to `.minimumLineSpacing = 0` and `.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0`), the visual result will make it *look* like there is 10-pts of spacing between the images:

[image]

Next, layout the collection view so it is 10-pts **wider** than the controller's view:

[image]

As you drag, it will appear that we have 10-pts of spacing between the cells:

[image]

and `.isPagingEnabled = true` will "snap" the cell into place:

[image]

Here is a complete example - Note: **This is *Sample Code Only!!***

Basic cell class with a `UIImageView`:

```
class PhotoDetailCVCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let imgView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        contentView.addSubview(imgView)

        // constrain image view
        imgView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            //  top/bottom
            make.top.bottom.equalTo(contentView)
            //  leading/trailing inset by 5-pts
            make.leading.trailing.equalTo(contentView).inset(5.0)
        }

    }
    
}
```

Example controller class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    let cvCellIdentifier: String = "photoCVCell"
    
    var mCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var imgNames: [String] = [
        "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5",
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        
        mCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        mCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        mCollectionView.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(mCollectionView)
        
        // respect safe area
        mCollectionView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            // top/bottom equal to safe area
            make.top.bottom.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
            // leading/trailing equal to safe area inset by -5.0
            //  this makes the collection view 10-pts WIDER than the view
            //  so having 5-pts "spacing" on each side of the cell's imageView
            //  will give the appearance of 10-pts spacing between cells
            make.leading.trailing.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide).inset(-5.0)
        }

        // if you're using a XIB for your cell
        //mCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "PhotoDetailCVCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cvCellIdentifier)
        
        // if you're using code (as in this example) for your cell
        mCollectionView.register(PhotoDetailCVCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cvCellIdentifier)
        
        mCollectionView.dataSource = self
        mCollectionView.delegate = self
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        // set collection view itemSize here, since we now know
        //  the frame size of the collection view
        if let layout = mCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.itemSize = mCollectionView.frame.size
        }
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imgNames.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cvCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PhotoDetailCVCell
        
        // try to load the image from Assets
        if let img = UIImage(named: imgNames[indexPath.item]) {
            cell.imgView.image = img
        } else {
            // could not  load image from Assets, so create a systemName image
            if let img = UIImage(systemName: "\(indexPath.item).square.fill") {
                cell.imgView.image = img
            }
        }
        
        // set image view background color if you want to see its frame
        //cell.imgView.backgroundColor = .lightGray

        return cell
    }
    
}
```

Comment: yeah, I do the same thing at last. Nice thought, man.

Answer (score 0):

It confuses me for days and I found the solution in the end. The solution is simple. The `isPagingEnabled` is decided by the frame of the collectionView so what we need is to make the size of the collectionView large than the frame of the window. We can just set the `minimumLineSpacing` and set the layout of collectionView so that it would stretch out to the right. Then we will get a interval between two cells and the page just works well.

Here is the code:

```
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
view.addSubview(mCollectionView)
mCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
mCollectionView.backgroundColor = .white
mCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "PhotoDetailCVCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cvCellIdentifier)
mCollectionView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.left.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    make.right.equalToSuperview().offset(10)
}
```